# Wine cdrom mount locations on Linux Mint 10 (Ubuntu 10.10) -- problems post install/switching discs

Tags: ubuntu, wine

I've been trying to install a few windows games with wine on Linux Mint 10 (based on ubuntu 10.10), but I am finding that my cd-rom mount points aren't standard.

ie: rather than /media/cdrom I get /media/disc_name [ a la /media/Warcraft\ III]

This seems to cause problems during the installation of multi-disc games, and games which require the disc to be in the drive after installation. In both cases the target disc cannot be found, even when the mount point is verified to match the original installation source, or updated in the installer to match the location of the second disc due to autonaming.

Any ideas what I could do here? Near all cases result in a file not found error.

Comment: The following links may help — you probably want to configure HAL in some way but I don't know exactly how. [Ubuntu - How to automount an external drive at a preconfigured mount point?](http://superuser.com/questions/16823/); [A different approach…HAL](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2005/09/19/a-different-approach-hal/); [TipsAndTricks/HAL](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/HAL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind mounting the disks manually, add the following line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/cdrom  /media/cdrom  auto  noauto,user,exec
```

Then you can use `mount /media/cdrom` when you insert a disk, and `umount /media/cdrom` before ejecting it.

You'll need to either figure out how to disable any automatic mounting, or undo that automatic mounting (with `umount`). You can also move a mount point with `mount --move ' /media/Warcraft III' /media/cdrom` (this needs to be run as root).

Comment: I'll test these out tonight and see what I find. For now I'm accepting your answer, combined with the comment :)